# zurb foundation and events on ajax loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, zurb-foundation

I was wondering if there is a possibility to reinitialize foundation after the content was changed with ajax.

In my case I am trying to reinitialize foundations abide form validation on a form that is passed back from an ajax call.

I tried to just call 
`$(document).foundation()`
which should reinit all the javascript ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

nice, I found out how to reinitialize the abide validation on my form

just call

`$(document).foundation('abide','events');`

Comment: Not sure that I get this. You just call `(document).foundation('abide','events');` after the event? Because that isn't working for me :-S

Comment: try it with an $ at the beginning $(document).foundation('abide','events'); not (document).foundation('abide','events');

Comment: Ahh, sorry, of ofcourse there is an $, well `jQuery` actually. Use it in Angular

Answer (score 0):

While this seems to still work for now in Foundation 5, there's an updated way to correctly do this in Foundation 5:

```
$('#yourFormID').foundation({bindings:'events'});
```